# Eager execution of tf.dataset instances

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I build a `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` with version 2.0. My input is a one-dimensional array, which contains indexes for clipping a large numpy array (60 GB).

My Pipeline so far reads the array with `np.memmap` and should then clips this array. Therefore, I create an array in the dimensions `(n, 4)`, where n is the number of samples. This `(n, 4)` array is prompted to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`.

Afterwards I want to call `dataset.map()`, where the input is one row if the `(n, 4)` array, which has the shape of `[4,]`. However,  I can not eval the single values of the this tensor, whereas I can evaluate the tensor before the `.map()` call.

Here is a minimal working example with the error I get:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

large_array = np.random.random((200, 200, 200))
train_array = np.random.randint(0, 50, (10, 4))

def slice_from_tensor(x):
    #heigth, width, heigth_exapnd, width_exapnd = tf.split(x, 4) # Both methods fail
    print(x)
    heigth, width, heigth_exapnd, width_exapnd = x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]

    return tf.convert_to_tensor(large_array[heigth: heigth+heigth_exapnd, 
                                  width: width+width_exapnd, :])


train_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_array)
train_slices_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_tensor)
print(train_slices_set)
train_set = train_slices_set.map(slice_from_tensor)
```

Error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-d059560c2557> in <module>
      3 train_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_array)
      4 train_slices_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_tensor)
----> 5 train_set = train_slices_set.map(slice_from_tensor)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in map(self, map_func, num_parallel_calls)
   1021     """
   1022     if num_parallel_calls is None:
-> 1023       return MapDataset(self, map_func, preserve_cardinality=True)
   1024     else:
   1025       return ParallelMapDataset(

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, input_dataset, map_func, use_inter_op_parallelism, preserve_cardinality, use_legacy_function)
   3008         self._transformation_name(),
   3009         dataset=input_dataset,
-> 3010         use_legacy_function=use_legacy_function)
   3011     variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.map_dataset(
   3012         input_dataset._variant_tensor,  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in __init__(self, func, transformation_name, dataset, input_classes, input_shapes, input_types, input_structure, add_to_graph, use_legacy_function, defun_kwargs)
   2398       resource_tracker = tracking.ResourceTracker()
   2399       with tracking.resource_tracker_scope(resource_tracker):
-> 2400         self._function = wrapper_fn._get_concrete_function_internal()
   2401         if add_to_graph:
   2402           self._function.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1328     """Bypasses error checking when getting a graph function."""
   1329     graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
-> 1330         *args, **kwargs)
   1331     # We're returning this concrete function to someone, and they may keep a
   1332     # reference to the FuncGraph without keeping a reference to the

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1322     if self.input_signature:
   1323       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1324     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1325     return graph_function
   1326 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   1585           or call_context_key not in self._function_cache.missed):
   1586         self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 1587         graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   1588         self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   1589         return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   1518             arg_names=arg_names,
   1519             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 1520             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   1521         self._function_attributes)
   1522 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    699                                           converted_func)
    700 
--> 701       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    702 
    703       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, IndexedSlices,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in wrapper_fn(*args)
   2392           attributes=defun_kwargs)
   2393       def wrapper_fn(*args):  # pylint: disable=missing-docstring
-> 2394         ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
   2395         ret = self._output_structure._to_tensor_list(ret)
   2396         return [ops.convert_to_tensor(t) for t in ret]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py in _wrapper_helper(*args)
   2332         nested_args = (nested_args,)
   2333 
-> 2334       ret = func(*nested_args)
   2335       # If `func` returns a list of tensors, `nest.flatten()` and
   2336       # `ops.convert_to_tensor()` would conspire to attempt to stack

<ipython-input-45-9015e98ee7eb> in slice_from_tensor(x)
      5 
      6     return tf.convert_to_tensor(large_array[heigth: heigth+heigth_exapnd, 
----> 7                                   width: width+width_exapnd, :])
      8 

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little change. You're first trying to slice numpy array with tensors and then convert result to tensor. But instead you first need to convert `large_array` to tensor and then slice. So instead of

```
return tf.convert_to_tensor(large_array[heigth: heigth+heigth_exapnd,
                                  width: width+width_exapnd, :])
```

Do

```
return tf.convert_to_tensor(large_array)[heigth: heigth+heigth_exapnd,
                                  width: width+width_exapnd, :]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very simple fix :D